# How to Perform Segue With Delay

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

In my storyboard, I have a view as a splash screen. In this view, I already have a button like "Open Application" that is opening the menu view with a modal segue. But I also want screen to perform segue automatically, like after 2 seconds view appears.

Some code here:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"splashScreenSegue" sender:self];
}
```

As you can see, I already use performSegueWithIdentifier but it performs immediately. Is there a method to make it delay?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use GCD's `dispatch_after` to execute your segue code 2 seconds after the view appears, e.x:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"splashScreenSegue" sender:self];
    });
}
```

Additionally, please make sure that you remember to call the super implementation when overriding UIViewController's life cycle methods.

Comment: hmm very easy, huh? no surprise ^^ this code was confusing me: [self performSelector:@selector(showSplash) withObject:nil afterDelay: SPLASH_HIDE_DELAY]; I wondered that if there a way alike for segues. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is a better approach which lets the controller itself to handle dispatching issues. You can achieve it like this:
first create a method like this which later you will use its selector

```
- (void)showAnotherViewController{  
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueToAnotherViewController" sender:self];
}
```

Then when you want to show another view controller after delay use this line of code inside your current view controller:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showAnotherViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:yourDelayInSeconds];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by calling:

```swift
let delayInSeconds = 0.8
let segueIdentifier = "your segue id"
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delayInSeconds) { [unowned self] in
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifier, sender: nil)
}
```