# Sleep Command Not Working

Tags: ios, ipad, sleep, segue

I have a modal with some options on it for my iPad App. When an option is selected I want to remove the modal then segue to a new screen.

I want the original screen (that launched the modal) to be seen for two seconds before the new segue happens. Why will this code not work?

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
sleep(2.0);
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"normalPushSegue" sender:self];
```

This is what happens: When a button on the modal is pressed it freezes for two seconds then transitions extremely quickly to the `normalPushSegue` screen. Even if I put the sleep command into  `prepareForSegue` it still does the same thing.

Any ideas? Are there any other ways to delay a segue?

Comment: Perhaps look here!!!  http://jrwren.wrenfam.com/blog/2012/02/01/storyboard-custom-segue-for-custom-pushviewcontroller-animation/

Comment: Sorry I was basing the use of it from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025423/how-to-perform-segue-with-delay

Will not be using it again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `performSelector:afterDelay:` instead:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(performSegueWithIdentifier::) withObject:@"normalPushSegue" withObject:self afterDelay:2];
```