# Handling iOS logic

Tags: ios, xcode

I can't seem to use two NSTimer elements in the same .m file. I am trying to carry out the first if statement below when the clock hits 0, then start another timer in the same place with only 3 seconds after the code block is carried out. After that 3 seconds I simply want to use the following segue `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"someIdentifier" sender:self];`

```
- (void)setupGame{
seconds = 6;
timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %i",seconds];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(subtractTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
 - (void)subtractTime{
seconds--;
timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %i",seconds];
if(seconds == 0){
    [timer invalidate];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+done!"];
    timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"!"];
    label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+success! redirecting..."];
    }
}
//need a new method!
```

Can someone write me a method to handle this logic?

fixed * thanks =)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
 [super viewDidAppear:animated];

double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"someIdentifier" sender:self];
});
}
```

thanks for the delay tip [How to Perform Segue With Delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025423/how-to-perform-segue-with-delay)

Comment: Use `performSelector:withDelay`

Comment: `[self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod) withObject:self afterDelay:3.0];`