# Show page for few seconds and navigate to another page using Xcode swift

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9

I want to be able to stay on the page for 3 seconds without pressing a button then Goto to the next page using swift.

Comment: Use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`

Comment: you can use segue or push/present by yourself you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52038261/3308174)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **DispatchQueue.main.async** method and specify the time interval in seconds. Implement this in the viewDidLoad() method.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 3) {
            //your code to go to next page
}
```